# I cannot get an onEdit Trigger to populate Effective User or Active User

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Overall, I am creating a very simplified workflow and over-building for a simple problem. The script I have thus far can be found below.

The tracking sheet has two simple buttons, one that raises a number, one that lowers it. These numbers are being copied to another sheet for tracking. Where I'm running into an issue is the following:

1.) Ideally, any time the script is ran, the effective user's email populates in Cell E13. (Solved - inserted into triggers for increment and decrement, respectively).

2.) I would like to take two adjacent cells (B7 & C7) from the "Universal Tracking Sheet" and copy them to the History sheet. (C7 currently is copied automatically)

3.) I would like to populate an accurate timestamp in the third column on the History sheet. (any time I try to add a timestamp function, it starts a new row, I likely don't know the syntax or proper function).

```
function increment() {
  // variables for increment
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet History");

  // script for increment +1
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').getValue() + 1);

  // script for copy and paste range to second sheet
  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange('C7');
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination)

  // variables for user lookup
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

  ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet").getRange('E13').setValue(email)
}


function decrement() {
  // variables for increment
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet History");

  // script for increment +1
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').getValue() - 1);

  // script for copy and paste range to second sheet
  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange('C7');
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination)

  // variables for user lookup
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

  ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet").getRange('E13').setValue(email)
}
```

Any guidance on the two cell copy to the second sheet and the addition of a timestamp would be phenomenal.

Comment: Check you executions you will see that there are failures for that code in there and they probably could have led you to the problem on your own

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Setup an installable onEdit

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Universal Tracking Sheet');
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  sheet.getRange('E13').setvalue(email);
}
```

getEffectiveUser was mispelled.  I gather that you understand that this code runs on every edit of every page in this spreadsheet.

Comment: Hah, of course it was misspelled!   I did just put that script in, and unfortunately the same result. No populating email for even my login

Comment: You may need to make it installable as well.

Comment: And yes, ultimately the only major edits will be operated by the script anyway - so the email populating for any change, any sheet is acceptable.

Comment: You could also be collecting sheet name and range as well as old and new value.  However, you will find that you will not have access to the emails of all users.

Comment: The users are all in the same domain fortunately and is a pretty limited list - maybe 10 in total.

Comment: I attempted to use the onMyEdit script as well, and it's a no-go.

Comment: You have to create an installable onEdit trigger with that name as the handlerFunction name.  But onEdit may work.  I'm not sure.

Comment: I put the user lookup in to the increment installed trigger and it worked out actually! I just have to get the other points up and running

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, I ended up banging my head against my keyboard for a bit longer and figuring out my issues. Below is the script I used, copying a range to another sheet, executing the .getEffectiveUser command and populating the email.

Hopefully if anyone else has a similar question, this will help.

Note 1: any user wanting to use this script effectively will need to be using a desktop browser.

Note 2: Decrement as referenced in the original code is the same, just with a modifier of -1 in the line //script for increment +1

```html
function increment() {
  // variables for increment
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet History");
  

  // script for increment +1
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('C7').getValue() + 1);



  // variables for user lookup
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

  ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet").getRange('E11').setValue(email)

  ss.getSheetByName("Universal Tracking Sheet").getRange('D7').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");


  // script for copy and paste range to second sheet
  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange('B7:D7');
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly: true})
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).